# Disabling Skrollr on mobile/screen resize, then re-enabling on desktop

Tags: jquery, skrollr

How do I disable Skrollr on mobile, as well as accounting for screen resizes? (ie, destroying skrollr on screen resize would mean that everything breaks once the user resizes up again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jquery

```
$(function () {
  if ($(window).width() > 480) { // initialize Skrollr under 480px
    skrollr.init();
  } else {
    skrollr.init().destroy();
  }
  $(window).on('resize', function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 480) { // destroy Skrollr over 480px
      skrollr.init().destroy(); 
    } else {
      skrollr.init();
    }
  });
});
```